Understanding いつもは隠してあるわよ
I have difficulty making sense of いつもは隠してあるわよ in the below panel. From a grammatical perspective, it is odd to me to mix an adverb いつもは with a verb that describes a resultative state 隠してある. I assume it means いつもは(銃が)隠してあるわよ, or "normally, that gun is kept hidden!"? But if that's case, his comment「もしかして俺を牽制してんの?」will not make sense. I suspect there is a typo: いつもは隠してあるわよ is supposed to be いつものは隠してあるわよ, meaning "the gun I normally use is kept hidden!"?

(Source: she is beautiful chapter 43)

How do you understand 牽制?

@aguijonazo to restrain, no?

いつもは(銃を)隠してあるわよ means "I normaly keep hiding that gun, ( but right now I don't hide it).
いつものは隠してあるわよ means "I keep hiding that gun you know. (I keep hiding  it right now).
So your making sentense doesn't make sense in this situation, because she wants to show him that gun in order to check(contain, restrain) him, and in fact she put that gun on the rear seat of the car.
